# Xamarin iOS On-demand resources

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mono, xamarin.ios

Does anyone have a good example of how to implement On-Demand resources in a Xamarin iOS project? I can't seem to find much documentation on how this would be done in Xamarin. Basically, I have some videos that I need to play from the app and in order to keep the app size small, I want to implement On-Demand resources.

Here are the resources I have found so far:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/tvos/application-fundamentals/resources-data-storage/#On-Demand-Resources

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_6.0/xamarin.studio_6.0/#On-Demand_Resources